# Cannot store URL link into MySQL using JSON and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

i need some wise advise about my college assignment.
My Job is to make a yearbooks using Phonegap and this is my first time using AJAX , JSON and JQuery Mobile.

Instead upload a image into the database , i try to upload an url link from my Google Drive.

Here my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#insert").click(function() {
            var nim = $("#NIM").val();
            var kesan = $("#kesan").val();
            var image = $('#image').val();
            var nama = $("#nama").val();
            var prodi = $("#prodi option:selected").text();
            var angkatan = $("#angkatan").val();
            var dataString = "nim=" + nim +  "&nama=" + nama + "&prodi=" + prodi + "&angkatan=" + angkatan +"&kesan=" + kesan + "&image=" + image + "&insert=";
            if ($.trim(nim).length > 0 & $.trim(kesan).length > 0 & $.trim(nama).length > 0 & $.trim(prodi).length > 0 & $.trim(angkatan).length > 0& $.trim(image).length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/perpusub/daftar.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("#insert").val('Memasukkan...');
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data == "success") {
                            alert("upload buku tahunan berhasil");
                            location="index.html";
                            $("#insert").val('submit');
                        } else {
                            alert("Mohon maaf tampaknya anda sudah pernah mengupload buku tahunan sebelumnya.\n Silahkan hubungi admin web ini.");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

this is my Form to upload the image and also store any information about each student:

```
<body>
    <div id="head1">
        Buat Halaman <br>Buku Tahunan Baru<br>
        <a href="index.html" class="button button-clear" id=head>Keluar</a>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="list">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" value="" />
        <div class="item">
            <label>NIM</label>
            <input type="text" id="NIM" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <label>Nama</label>
            <input type="text" id="nama" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <label>Prodi</label>
                    <select id="prodi">
                        <option value="TIF" selected>TEKNIK INFORMATIKA</option>
                        <option value="SI">SISTEM INFORMASI</option>
                        <option value="TKOM">TEKNIK KOMPUTER</option>
                        <option value="PTI">PENDIDIKAN TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI</option>
                        <option value="TI">TEKNIK INFORMASI</option>
                    </select>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <label>Angkatan</label>
            <input type="text" id="angkatan" value="" />
        </div>
                <div class="item">
            <label>Kesan Pesan</label>
            <input type="text" id="kesan" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        <label>Link File Foto<br></label>
           <input type="text" id="image" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <input type="submit" id="insert" class="button button-block" value="DAFTAR" />
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is the PHP code to store it into the database.

```
<?php
 include "db.php";
 if(isset($_POST['insert']))
 {
 $nim=$_POST['nim'];
 $kesan=$_POST['kesan'];
 $nama=$_POST['nama'];
 $prodi=$_POST['prodi'];
 $angkatan=$_POST['angkatan'];
 $image = $_POST['image'];

     $qa=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `anggota`(`NIM`, `nama`, `prodi`, `angkatan`, `kesanPesan`, `photo`) VALUES ('$nim','$nama','$prodi','$angkatan','$kesan','$foto')");
 if($qa){
       echo "success";
 }

 else{
     echo "error";
 }
 }


 }
 ?>
```

and this is the JSON decoder as yearbook pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "http://localhost/php-code/json.php";
    $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
            var id = field.id;
            var title = field.title;
            var duration = field.duration;
            var price = field.price;
            $("#listview").append("<a class='item' href='form.html?id=" + id + "&title=" + title + "&duration=" + duration + "&price=" + price + "'><span class='item-note'>$" + price + "</span><h2>" + title + " </h2><p>" + duration + "</p></a>");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

But when i decode JSON to show it into the list , it only show damaged image icon. I think there's problem when store link into database and decode it.

I need help because my assignment must be submited in two days. Thank you.

Comment: Update: i got new evidence why my picture not work , because JSON fail to decode only the URL. when there's a backslash (/) , it will change into like this (\/). Is anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible error sources here:

- You are not escaping special chars before inserting them into database. Use mysqli_prepare (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for that. Also this saves you from SQL injection attacks (more or less)
- Which PHP version are you using? In really old versions, like 5.4 and before, there was a switch to magically add backslashes before "evil" chars in get/post/cookie data. See [magic quotes configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime) for more information

Comment: I decide not to use prepare syntax intentionally due assignment deadline. And my php version  is the latest.